# Timestamp in db2 from string in python

Tags: python, timestamp, db2

I have a local database in mariaDB  from wich I read your records (timestamp convert to string) and I must write in db2 of Type  timestamp, I need help.
I am working in python

Finally, It turned out to be a format error. The format of the db2 is EUR no ISO, as I thought.

Result:
Select cast(date_format(MyColumn, 'EUR'))as char) from Mytable where condition;

Comment: Have you inserted the string into the DB2 timestamp column? DB2 converts it from most formats.

Comment: yes, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can insert timestamp with string value which respect format timestamp, like this:

```
insert into yourlib.yourtable (column1, columnwithtimestamp)
values ('hellocolumn1', '2016-12-21-10.04.37.766665')
```